# Enter data into a drop-down list

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need my webdriver testcase to write into a text box and choose an option from a drop-down list, but it is erroring.

This is my webdriver code:

```cs
namespace OneViewTestingUsingSelenium
{
  class ExcelLibary
  {
    private static DataTable ExcelTodataTable(string fileName)
    {
      //open this file and returns stream obj
      FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      //create open xml reader using excel reader factory
      IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
      //set 1st row as column name
      excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
      //return dataset
      DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
      //got all the tables
      DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
      //stores all the table into datatable
      DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];
      //ultimately return this
      return resultTable;
    }
    public static List<DataCollectionExcel> dataCol = new List<DataCollectionExcel>();

    public static void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
    {
      DataTable table = ExcelTodataTable(fileName);
      for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
      {
        for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
          DataCollectionExcel dtTable = new DataCollectionExcel
          {
            rowNumber = row,
            colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
            colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
          };
          dataCol.Add(dtTable);
        }
      }
    }
    public static string ReadDataExcel(int rowNumber, string columnName)
    {
      try
      {
        string data = (from coldata in dataCol
          where coldata.colName == columnName && coldata.rowNumber == rowNumber
          select coldata.colValue).SingleOrDefault();
        return data.ToString();
      }
      catch (Exception Ex)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
  public class DataCollectionExcel
  {
    public int rowNumber { get; set; }
    public string colName { get; set; }
    public string colValue { get; set; }
  }
}
```

---

In my webdriver testcase I am reading user information from Excel and entering it into a User Create page to create a new user.

When it enters data into a text box it has no problem, it works correctly; but when it enters data into both a text box and drop down list then I get an error.

I have tried the following:

```cs
IList<IWebElement> tit = SupportClass.driverFF.FindElements(By.Id("UserEntity_Master_Default_Title"));

int titCount = tit.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < titCount; i++)
{
    if (tit[i].Text == "Mr")
    {
        tit[i].Click();
    }
    if (tit[i].Text == "Mrs")
    {
        tit[i].Click();
    }
    if (tit[i].Text == "Miss")
    {
        tit[i].Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you got? Also please share the HTML code of the elements you are trying to automate.

Comment: You are basically trying to select a value from the dropdown using selenium. Where as the value to be selected from dropdown comes from external excel sheet. Am i right?

Comment: yes..i want do same thing which r u consider...actually i want to take data from excel and create new user as well as edit it in future.

Comment: hope you tried the answer i suggested after my recent edit

Comment: I have changed it again, `IWebElement tit = SupportClass.driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("UserEntity_Master_Default_Title"));` even after this you are getting the same error?

Comment: thank you a lot...its work fine..i nee one more help..how should i edit data can you tell me please..

Comment: Yes, let me know what exactly you want to do

Comment: how to modified existing data through excel..1st condition there are no edit button ,2nd when we click any row of grid view it will show all data,i have to take data from excel to modified!

Comment: Do you mean to say that, the data of the web page doesn't have a provision to edit, but still you want to modify the data on the webpage? Am i right? I guess you have  the code written to read data from Excel. Can you please post your entire selenium code?

Comment: yes have option ,when we click any row of grid view it will grant me permission for editing after click save button for save modify data...but my requirement is i have to modify data using excel..below is my code

Comment: While reading data from excel, store your desired data to variable, then you can use them in selenium code for editing

Comment: can you explain me in a details..thank u..

Comment: Okay, let me explain with an example. Let me assume that you have 4 fields in you  page 1. Name (Text Box), 2. Country (Drop Down) 3. Gender (Radio button) 5. Terms and Condition (Check box). Now that you want to fill in all these details. But you don't want to hard code the values in the selenium code but you want to take the data from excel and then use in selenium code. I thing my understanding so far is correct

Comment: Now you have a piece of code which you are using to read data from excel, With my example, you need Name,Country, Gender, T&C from excel. These values will be in any of the work sheets of your excel workbook. So create variables for Name,Country, Gender, T&C  in selenium code, while reading the excel, when you get the Name, assign it to your selenium variable, do the same for all variables. By the time, you are done reading excel data, you should have a set of variables which are holding Name,Country, Gender, T&C. Using these variables, you can simple automate the web page pushing these data.

Comment: Hope, you are able to under stand what i mean to say.

Comment: I understand but for this what should i do?can you provide me code for this example.

Comment: i tried to make it simple and had added new code in my previous answer.Please go through it and let me know if you are able to understand or should you have any clarifications

Comment: i did that when i create new user no problem but when i want to modify existing data that scenario what should i do?i need that purpose demo code

Comment: Do you mean to say when you open your form for an existing user? That mean, when you open all the fields will be filled, now you want to clear previous values and want to enter new values(taking from excel). If my understanding is right, then you will repeat same what you did for new. I dont' understand what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: yes when i open this form and i clicked any row of existing table(means grid-view where existing data were stored ) that's row data will be modified through excel data ..i think you will understand my problem

Comment: Nope can you please share me screen print of your form in different states, normal mode, edit mode(with row selected) and html code of the page when grid row is selected.

Comment: i completed it.thank you a lot

Comment: welcome and feel free to mark the question as answered

Comment: I have restructured your question, and rephrased much of the wording, to make it more clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To Select a value from a drop down with `Select` html tag, you cannot use `.Click` even though manually we use mouse clicks for drop down selection.What you need to do is use `SelectElement` class

Try below one

```
IWebElement tit = SupportClass.driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("UserEntity_Master_Default_Title"));
        SelectElement dropdownSelector = new SelectElement(tit);
        dropdownSelector.SelectByText(yourExcelInputStringHere);
```

You can aslo select values from dropdown by using`index` or `value`

```
dropdownSelector.SelectByIndex(1);
dropdownSelector.SelectByValue("1");
```

Edit:
Sample code for taking data from excel and feeding it as input to web forms

link used: http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/

Excel Test data[image]

Code:

```
namespace SeleniumTestDriver
{
   class Program
   {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringDictionary testData = new StringDictionary();
        testData = GetTestData();

        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        IWebElement txtbxFirstName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("firstname"));
        txtbxFirstName.SendKeys(testData["firstName"]);

}


public static StringDictionary GetTestData()
    {
        StringDictionary dataFromExcel = new StringDictionary();
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\1.xlsx");
        Excel.Worksheet xlSht1 = xlWb.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
        dataFromExcel.Add("firstName", xlSht1.Cells[2, 1].value);
        dataFromExcel.Add("lastName", xlSht1.Cells[2, 2].value);
        dataFromExcel.Add("gender", xlSht1.Cells[2, 3].value);
        dataFromExcel.Add("tool", xlSht1.Cells[2, 4].value);
        dataFromExcel.Add("continent", xlSht1.Cells[2, 5].value);
        xlWb.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();
        return dataFromExcel;

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I used before but i got error...canot convert from system.collection.generic>IList<OpenQA.Selenium>IWebElement> to OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement ..

Comment: you are using `FindElements` but what i have in my answer is `FindElement`, change it, it will work